# Running Hadoop in stand alone mode: bin/hadoop: line 350: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.O/bin/java: No such file or directory

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop

I know these kind of question were asked tons of time's, but still i couldn’t figure my specific problem

i have installed `Hadoop`, and got all the required jar's:

```
yosh@yosh-VirtualBox:~/hadoop$ ls
hadoop-1.2.1  hadoop-1.2.1.tar.gz

yosh@yosh-VirtualBox:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1$ ls
bin          hadoop-ant-1.2.1.jar          input        README.txt
build.xml    hadoop-client-1.2.1.jar       ivy          sbin
c++          hadoop-core-1.2.1.jar         ivy.xml      share
CHANGES.txt  hadoop-examples-1.2.1.jar     lib          src
conf         hadoop-minicluster-1.2.1.jar  libexec      webapps
contrib      hadoop-test-1.2.1.jar         LICENSE.txt
docs         hadoop-tools-1.2.1.jar        NOTICE.txt
```

and ive set the variables in the profile as required:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.o
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.8.o
PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin
HADOOP_INSTALL=/home/hadoop/Hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1
PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

ive got java installed:

```
yosh@yosh-VirtualBox:~$ java -version
java version "1.8.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)
```

and im also able to echo JAVA_HOME

```
yosh@yosh-VirtualBox:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.O
```

Ive seen some other SO questions that mention that i should edit the hadoop-config.sh

So i tried this as well (in that file):

```
# we use in Hadoop. Tune the variable down to prevent vmem explosion.
export MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=${MALLOC_ARENA_MAX:-4}   
export HADOOP_HOME=${HADOOP_PREFIX}
export HADOOP_HOME 
_WARN_SUPPRESS=1
export $JAVA_HOME # ive added here the java home
```

So im trying to run Hadoop in stand alone mode, but when im running Hadoop (ive already created input and copies there some text files), i get:

```
yosh@yosh-VirtualBox:~/hadoop/hadoop-1.2.1$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-*.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
bin/hadoop: line 350: /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.O/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I just cant find an answer to this, any help will be highly appreciated!!!

BTW im using Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: `O` instead of `0` maybe?

Comment: is /usr/local/java/jdk1.8.O directory exist ..??

Comment: Where should i change the o and 0 ?

Comment: yosh@yosh-VirtualBox:~$ cd usr
bash: cd: usr: No such file or directory

Comment: I don’t understand, if i can see this file in java - version, how come it doesn't exists?

Comment: Yes it worked!!! indeed o instead of 0!!!!! dear fge, please post this as answer, so ill up vote + accept :)

Comment: You need address him with a @fge, so he will see your message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo!

You have:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.O
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
JRE_HOME=/usr/local/java/jre1.8.O
PATH=$PATH:$JRE_HOME/bin
```

`O` is not `0` ;) Change these and it should be OK.

Also, why define both `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME`? I have a hunch that they are the same; to confirm, try and:

```
$ echo $(readlink -e $JAVA_HOME)
$ echo $(readlink -e $JRE_HOME)
```

If those are the same you can just drop `JRE_HOME`. And I suspect Hadoop would prioritize `JAVA_HOME` anyway.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me tons of time, hadoop works, do you think i should still drop the `JRE_HOME` ?

Comment: Well, try and drop it, I honestly believe it won't make a difference

Comment: yosh@yosh-VirtualBox:~$ echo $(readlink -e $JAVA_HOME)
/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0
yosh@yosh-VirtualBox:~$ echo $(readlink -e $JRE_HOME)
/usr/local/java/jre1.8.0

Comment: ok thanks, i think ill leave it, if things work, why change them?

Comment: Your choice... I'd personally choose to drop it ;)